# Soft-Question: Which music instrument(s) is in the background along with piano

Tags: instruments

Here is a relaxing piano music:

What is the instrument played in the background of piano music?

Noise like sound in low volume.

Is this a drum?

Comment: Google "jazz trio" It's piano bass & drums, played with brushes.

Comment: This question is made for Music Fans SE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those are known as *brushes*, they are played on drums by "sweeping" them on the surface of the drum (usually the snare) not unlike a common "brush", and there are various techniques used to also hit the heads, since they're obviously not as hard as sticks and their behavior and rebounds are very different, requiring different control.